# $x^4 + y^4 \mod p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The primes $p = 5, 13, 17, 29$ have the property that there exist fewer than $p$ values for $x^4 + y^4 \mod p$.  For example, $x^4 \equiv 0$ or $1 \mod 5$ so $x^4 + y^4 \equiv 0, 1$ or $2$, but never $3$ or $4$, $\mod 5$.  Are there any other primes with this property?

The question arose in connection with [OEIS sequence A289559](https://oeis.org/A289559)

Comment: None up through 3300.

Comment: Just finished checking through 10000. It's looking like there aren't going to be any other primes with fewer than $p$ values of $x^4+y^4$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Here's some argument for the above. There should be about $(p-1)/4$ distinct fourth powers, so about $\frac{p-1}{4}+\binom{(p-1)/4}{2}$ sums of two fourth powers. But this is $<p$ precisely when $p<30.1.$

Comment: See Joe Silverman's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356270/does-the-expression-x4-y4-take-on-all-values-in-mathbbz-p-mathbbz), which indicates that there are no other primes.

Answer (score 3):

For a given prime $p$, let $Z_p$ denote the ring of integers, mod $p$, and let $f\colon Z_p^2 \to Z_p$ be defined by $f(x,y) = x^4+y^4$.

Partial result: If $p \equiv -1\;\,(\text{mod}\;4)$, then $f$ is surjective.

Proof:

Assume $p$ is a prime, with $p \equiv -1\;\,(\text{mod}\;4)$.

Then $-1$ is not a quadratic residue, mod $p$.

Claim every square in $Z_p$ is also a $4$-th power.

Let $a,b \in Z_p^{*}$, and suppose $a^4=b^4$ in $Z_p$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then in $Z_p$,}\;\;&a^4=b^4\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^2=\pm b^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a^2=b^2&&\text{[since $-1$ is not a quadratic residue, mod $p$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a= \pm b\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It follows that the map $Z_p^{*} \to Z_p^{*}$ given by $x \mapsto x^4$ is exactly two-to-one, hence the set of $4$-th powers in $Z_p^{*}$ has cardinality $\frac {p-1}{2}$. Of course every $4$-th power is also a square, hence, since the cardinalities are the same, the set of $4$-th powers in $Z_p^{*}$ is the same as the set of squares in $Z_p^{*}$, which (since $0$ is also a $4$-th power), proves the claim.

For any $k \in Z_p$ which is not a square in $Z_p$,
$$Z_p = \{x^2 \mid x \in Z_p\} \cup \{kx^2 \mid x \in Z_p^{*}\}$$
Fix  $k \in \{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$ as the least positive integer such that $k$ is not a square in $Z_p$. Then $k > 1$, and $k-1$ is a square in $Z_p$.

Fix $r$ is $Z_p$. We want to show $r$ is in the image of $f$.

If $r$ is a square in $Z_p$, then $r$ is a $4$-th power in $Z_p$, hence $f(x,0)=r$, for some $x$, so $r$ is in the image of $f$.

Next, suppose $r$ is not a square in $Z_p$.

Then $r=kx^2$, for some $x \in Z_p$, and $(k-1)x^2$ is a square in $Z_p$.

Let $y$ be such that $y^2 = (k-1)x^2$ in $Z_p$. 
\begin{align*}
\text{Then in $Z_p$,}\;\;&y^2=(k-1)x^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2+y^2=kx^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2+y^2=r\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\text{$r$ is the sum of two squares}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\text{$r$ is the sum of two $4$-th powers}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $r$ is in the image of $f$, as required.